# Django convert list of string numbers into the integers doesn't work

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

I have a huge problem with **scraping** data and convert number string to integer.

```
salary = p.find('div', class_='details-body__content').text
a = []
x = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', salary)
a.append(x)
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = int(a[i])
print(a)
```

This code isn't working and i dunno why, i tried all options from SOF and from google.

Comment: could you please provide example of input? what the ```salary``` is?

Comment: Salary it's a salary from a scrapped website and my output is TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'  while print(a) its: [['36', '25', '8', '30', '4', '30', '45', '30', '24', '162', '32', '25', '725', '4', '12']]

Answer (score 1):

as you mention in comment `a` has follwing structure:

```
a = [['36', '25', '8', '30', '4', '30', '45', '30', '24', '162', '32', '25', '725', '4', '12']]
```

and it's a list which contains list with your values :)
so you need to get the list with values and then loop through it:

```
a = a[0] # here, get list with values
print(a)
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = int(a[i])
print(a)
```